# Weird euro symbol in java mail attachment

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jakarta-mail

When I send mail with following code in attachment instead of EURO symbol I am getting some weird character like this "â‚¬;". I already set the content type of message as UTF-8 as well for OutputStreamWriter as well. What could be the reason for this?

```
    public static void sendMail(String email, String password, String sendTo, String subject, String msg)
    {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

      final String fEMail = email;
      final String fPassword = password;

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
      {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(fEMail, fPassword);
        }
      });

      try
      {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(email));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("to mail address"));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent("Hi", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");


        File file = File.createTempFile("test", ".csv");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        writer.println("\u20ac;");
        writer.println("€");
        writer.flush();

        MimeMultipart rootMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
        bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(file)));
        bodyPart.setFileName(file.getName());
        rootMultipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
        message.setContent(rootMultipart);

        Transport.send(message);

        writer.close();
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");

      }
      catch (MessagingException e)
      {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fix all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

The first message.setContent call does nothing because it's overridden by the second message.setContent call.  To create a message with an attachment, the Multipart needs to contain a body part for the main message body and additional body parts for the attachments.

Remove the second writer.println call.

The real problem is most likely that, when you attach the file, it's choosing the wrong charset for the data.  Try setting the System property "mail.mime.charset" to "utf-8".

Comment: Just before your call to Transport.send, add message.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"));.  Then check msg.txt to see if it has the proper charset for your text part.  What program are you using to view the message?

Comment: MS excel as its a csv.

Comment: You probably need to tell Excel that the file is using the utf-8 charset instead of the default charset for your locale.  Or, you need to find a way to convert the file from the utf-8 charset to the default charset for your locale.